# Why does 'dispatch' method only instantiate and return of PendingDispatch without scheduling it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am an PHP/Laravel newbie. I am working with Laravel job and everything works fine.
However, when I have a look at the implementation of dispatch method, it looks weird to me.

```
if (! function_exists('dispatch')) {
    /**
     * Dispatch a job to its appropriate handler.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $job
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch
     */
    function dispatch($job)
    {
        return new PendingDispatch($job);
    }
}
```

I would expect some code that enqueues the job or at least triggers something to schedule the job to be executed later on. However, the method only creates an instance of PendingDispatch and returns it. I also checked the PendingDispatch constructor and found nothing relevant.

Could anyone please help me to understand how the job is scheduled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever we dispatch a job in laravel, i call the helper that you have mentioned in question, afterwards PendingDispatch($job) is called where job is assigned in constructor, if you can look at the destructor  in same file you will find the below code

```
public function __destruct()
{
    app(Dispatcher::class)->dispatch($this->job);
}
```

This method, when called, will resolve an instance of Dispatcher from the container and call the dispatch() method on it. A __destruct() is a PHP magic method that's called when all references to the object no longer exist or when the script terminates, and since we don't store a reference to the PendingDispatch instance anywhere the __destruct method will be called immediately

Comment: Indeed, I did not look at the destructor. I have never seen this kind of pattern before where code are invoked in destruction step. It makes sure that the job is really _enqueued_ when we have nothing else to do with the PendingDispatch instance. Thanks.